# __call__ method of type class

Tags: python, metaclass

From all I understand about Python object oriented programming if a class has `__call__` method defined that would be invoked if we use the instance of the class like a function call. For example:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,sal):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = sal
    def __call__(self,value):
        return self.salary * value

e = Employee("Subhayan",20000)
print (e(10))
```

So the `__call__` method takes the object instance as the first argument.

I am just trying to understand metaclasses in Python and I read that `type` is the default metaclass of all user defined classes.

If I define a basic custom metaclass in Python:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        # Run by inherited type.__call__
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict)
```

Now as per the documentation given in the book the metaclass `__new__` method would be run by the `__call__` method inherited from type.

Now my question is to use the `__call__`  method of any class we have to have an object of that class and then call it as a function.

Here we don't have any object of type to use its `__call__` function.

Can someone please explain to me how is the `__call__` function of type class coming into picture?

Answer (score 6):

Any class is itself an instance of type "type" - therefore "calling" a class just calls the method `__call__` on its class - which happens to be type's `__call__`.
The effect of `type.__call__` is exactly: 
on code like:

```
class A:
    pass
b = A()
```

1. `type.__call__` receives the class `A` itself as its first parameter.
2. It calls the `A.__new__` - in pseudocode we could write `instace = A.__new__(cls)` as what runs.
3. That returns an instance of the "A" class
4. Then it calls `__init__` on the instance(`instance.__init__()`)
5. ...and returns that instance `return instance`

However, if the the class itself is derived from "type" - i.e., it is the instantiation of a "new" class, extra steps are taken:  The special value of the magic `__class__` variable is filled in any of the class methods - if any of those methods use a call to `super`. And on Python 3.6, these 2 further steps: any of the class attributes that define a  `__set_name__` method are called, and the class's `__init_subclass__` method is called.

Comment: I will open a new question since i am still not clear when the class is itself derived from type. I will paste a new code there, so please help me with that as well.

Comment: Also until a class is created it is not an instance of type yet. So when in the above code A() is called then i can understand the __call__  method of type getting invoked. But __new__ should get called as soon as the class statement in run. But as you mentioned __new__ is getting called from __call__. Not sure if i understand correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, `type` is a metaclass so it's instances are classes, not objects. Than means (among other things) that when you do this:

```
e= Employee(*args,**kwargs)
```

You are calling `Employee.__init__` and some methods from your metaclass including `Meta.__call__`, the same way that when you do .

```
print (e(10))
```

you are invoking your custom `__call__` method.

Take for example this `Singleton` metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
```

Now every time you create a new instance of `MyClass`, the `__call__` method in the metaclass is called **before** the actual instance is created allowing you to check if a previous one exists and return that instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One question here. Inside Singleton __call__ function the cls argument would have the value of MyClass. And _instances belongs to the Singleton class .How can then MyClass have the _instances dictionary?

Comment: Because `MyClass` is an instance of `Singleton`.

Comment: Subhayan: ...and all `Singleton` instances share the same `_instances` dictionary since it's a class, _not_ an instance, attribute.