# Overwrite __call__ method of third party class at runtime, while maintaining other methods

Tags: python

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
       A
       |
 _____________
 |     |     |
Foo   Bar   Baz
```

The class `A` defines a `__call__` method, which `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` implement. The classes also define various other methods I'm interested in. All three classes come from a third party library, so I do not want to change their implementation. However, in some cases **at runtime**, I would like to alter the implementation of `Foo`'s, `Bar`'s and `Baz`' `__call__` method. Right now, I did this by defining my own classes, which solely override the `__call__` method:

```
Foo   Bar   Baz
 |     |     |
Foo1  Bar1  Baz1
```

Then, depending on the situation, I instantiate the desired class to a common variable. I'm not satisfied with this solution, as it has the following drawbacks:

- The additions I make to `__call__` are not necessarily uniquely determined by the class. `Bar1` and `Baz1` might share the implementation of `__call__` (but `Bar` and `Baz` differ in other aspects). So, as far as I understand, I need to repeat code.
- At runtime, instantiating the desired class requires *m* × *n* case distinctions (where *m* is the number of classes at the level of `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` and *n* is the number of classes at the level of `Foo1`, `Bar1`, and `Baz1`). This will grow rapidly as *m* or *n* increase. Ideally, I would like the number of case distinction to be *m* + *n*.

I already had a look at https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/composition-over-inheritance/#solution-3-the-decorator-pattern, at [Cannot overwrite implementation for __call__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817015/cannot-overwrite-implementation-for-call) and at [__call__ method of type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178162/call-method-of-type-class). However, these solutions do not fit perfectly to my case, as (1) I'm overriding a dunder method (2) of third party classes and (3) still would like to have access to the other class methods of `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`.

Is there an elegant why to achieve what I am looking for?

Edit: The change of `__call__` at runtime should only affect the instance object, not the class or all objects of that class at once.

Edit 2 (requested by @enzo):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        """Docstring A"""
    
    @abstractmethod
    def method1(self, a, b):
        """Docstring method1"""

class Foo(A):
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x + y # indeed, no dependence on `self`
    
    def method1(self, a, b):
        # but this might depend on `self`
        pass

class Bar(A):
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x * y # indeed, no dependence on `self`
    
    def method1(self, a, b):
        # but this might depend on `self`
        pass

    def method2(self, c, d):
        # but this might depend on `self`
        pass

class Baz(A):
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x ** y # indeed, no dependence on `self`
    
    def method1(self, a, b):
        # but this might depend on `self`
        pass

    def method2(self, c, d):
        # but this might depend on `self`
        pass
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code, such as dummy implementations of `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` which simulates the original classes' behavior?

Comment: @enzo see edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you meant, but based on your sample code you could do something like this:

```py
# Create a decorator to keep the reference to the original __call__'s
class CustomA(A):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return self.obj(x, y)
        
    def method1(self, a, b):
        return self.obj.method1(a, b)
        
# Create a decorator that calls the original __call__
class MultiplyA(CustomA):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__(obj)
        
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        result = super().__call__(x, y)
        return result * 10
        
# Create a decorator that ignores the original __call__
class DivideA(CustomA):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__(obj)
        
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        # You can still access the original object' attributes here
        super().method1(x, y)
        return x / y
```

Usage:

```
foo = Foo()
print(foo(1, 2))
# Outputs 3

foo = MultiplyA(foo)
print(foo(1, 2))
# Outputs 30

bar = Bar()
print(bar(2, 3))
# Outputs 6

bar = DivideA(bar)
print(bar(10, 5))
# Outputs 2.0
```

Comment: From what I understand, I need to implement in `CustomA` the forwarding to `__call__`, `method1` (and other methods I did not show here), so I may focus in the other decorators on just altering the `__call__`s?

Answer (score 0):

you can inject a custom call into it:

```
class A():
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In A.__call__")

    def showCall(self):
        print(self.__call__)

class foo(A):
    pass

class bar(A):
    pass

class baz(A):
    pass

def my_custom_func():
    print("In my custom func")

f = foo()
f()

b = bar()
b()

f.showCall()
b.showCall()

print("##setting call##")
f.__call__ = my_custom_func
print("##running f calls##")
f.showCall()
f()

print("##running b calls##")
b.showCall()
b()
```

While this does solve your injection problem other things might come into play where you still need the original `__call__` method. In which case you will need to save them before setting them.

Comment: It seems that in this solution you require to alter the definition of `A`. Is that correct?

Comment: No. A stays as is. All you're doing is changing what function gets called on the instance of Foo or Bar. The underlying class stays the same

Comment: When I execute your code with python3, all 4 calls of `showCall()` result in `In A.__call__`. None of them prints `In my custom func`.